# Convert beveled curve to rigged mesh

Tags: rigging, armature, bezier-curves

Is there a way to convert a **beveled curve into a rigged mesh**? I would like to have a rigged rope in a way where the **bone weights are calculated from the curve control points**, so if I have 2 control points it will be converted into 2 bones, and when I pose them, they will deform the mesh similar to control points?